# Stop MATE panel being dragged with touch

Tags: 22.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, touchscreen, mate-panel

I have a touch screen computer running Ubuntu MATE 22.04.

When I accidentally touch on the MATE panel, the panel is dragged to another location, which is very inconvenient, because sometimes I end up dislocating the panel while trying to move an window.

However, when I try to drag the panel with mouse, nothing happens (as expected).

How to stop the panel from being dragged when I touch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An workaround is to not use the Cupertino layout, as it is the only layout where the [bug](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/issues/1360) is present.